# Ajax form submit even when JavaScript is disabled in a browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

P.S - The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212182/submitting-form-using-javascript-when-javascript-is-disabled) **did not** help.

Also, as for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled), I am not sure how to implement the feature that was mentioned by the community wiki

We have a form whose data are being submitted using Ajax only in PHP and Laravel.  That is not a big deal because the form can be submitted using regular submit.

But there are certain things that only Ajax request will do. As an example. uploading a file **to a temporary folder**, **before** submitting the form. Now, I dont want to use normal submit to do that.
Apart from that, there are other things like getting OTP to mobile and all that.

So, is there any way to disable the page completely when JavaScript is disabled? Meaning apart from a warning message that "JavaScript must be enabled", the user will not be able to do anything.

I am aware of a tag called `<noscript>` but will that help in my case?

Comment: Browsers don't load javascript files if js is disabled, you can set a coockie or something or use something like this `<noscript><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;gotoNoJSPage.html"></noscript>` to redirect the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't load javascript files if js is disabled, you can set a coockie or something or use something like this

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;gotoNoJSPage.html"></noscript>
```

to redirect the user